# Regex Python Extract Informations

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I wonder if there's a way in python to be able to extract the informations from a line like the example below and put it in a 
table:

```
table = [ Time: 01:09:25.258, O:Localhost, R:192.168.1.1 id:62 ] 

data = "01:09:25.258 mta   Messages  I Doc O:Localhost   R:192.168.1.1   id:62 "
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be better answered, see the [FAQ], especially [ASK].

Comment: well i want to split the data and put it in a table, i've tried this way but it doesn't work ( i'm beginner in python.. )
import re 

data = "01:09:25.258 mta Messages I Doc O:Localhost R:192.168.1.1 id:62 "
id = re.finditer(r"\id:(\d+)\, data ) 
O = re.finditer(r"\O:(\d+)\, data ) 
R = re.finditer(r"\R:(\d+)\, data ) 

tab = [ id, O, R ] 
print tab

Comment: I am sure you want to do a lot of things, but the garbage you posted above is useless. If you want help, you will need to post actual code, some actual examples, and not assume we can read your mind or know what you want to acomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task, I think using a dictionary would be a good idea. You could do something like this:

```
import re

data = "Time:01.09.25.258 O:Localhost R:192.168.1.1 id:62 "

result = {}
for i in data.split():
    j, k = re.findall(r'[^: ]+', i)
    result[j] = k

print(result) #Prints {'id': '62', 'O': 'Localhost', 'Time': '01.09.25.258', 'R': '192.168.1.1'}
```

Comment: Great That was exactly what i was looking for now i'll have to edit it because my messages are much longer than that ;D thanks for your help !